# Jquerymobile Footer hiding and showing again with button

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

I want to add show and hide button for fixed footer on jquerymobile.
I tried to add an close button but i did not do.

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed"></div>
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I made a Collapsible Block. Like this:

```
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h1>Click me - I'm collapsible!</h1>
  <p>I'm the expanded content.</p>
</div>
```